# In a Python Function, write the pandas result to a CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, if-statement

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfBwe.jpg)Hello I am trying to write a script in which I look at some historical data (Stock Prices) and compute a rolling Linear Regression Slope.

I have a CSV file with the Close Price of AAPL US Equity from 01-01-2010 - 10-23-2020.

As you can see in the below code I have read the CSV, created a few new variables, The Moving Linear Slope etc...  and wrote that data into the CSV as new columns. PS: ROC is the Rate of Change of the MLR Slope.

I am now trying to create a function which returns 1,0,-1 (1=Long, 0 = No Position, -1=Short) for each date/stock price. I have created the below function "scorer"  but am unable to figure out how to get it to look at each date and write the corresponding value into a new column in the CSV.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import talib as ta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("Copper.csv")
score = 0

mlrs = ta.LINEARREG_SLOPE(data["Close"].values,14)*-1
sma = data.MlrSlope.rolling(14).mean()
roc = data.MlrSlope.rolling(5).mean()

#Create new columns for Roc and SMA. We then Write the new Column data to the CSV file. This should add both the ROCC and SMA Columns. 
data["Rocc"] = roc
data["SMA"] = sma
data.to_csv("copper.csv",index=True)

# The below function looks to check for the SMA & MLR Slope being Positive... ***JOSHUA BEFORE FINISHING*** add another parameter that looks at the ROC of the MLR Slope... This would be my "roc" variable. If the change is very negative very quick it could resemble an exit opportunity on the Long Side, while a sharp Up Turn could indicate a Buy Opportunity.  
def scorer(data):
    if(data["sma"] > 0 and data["MlrSlope"] >0 ):
            return 1
        elif (data["sma"] >0 and data["MlrSlope"] <0):
            return 0
        elif(data["sma"] <0 and data["MlrSlope"] >0):
            return 0
        elif (data["sma"] <0 and data["MlrSlope"] <0):
            return -1
```

Comment: Hi Jstern15. Can you provide an example of the dataframe you are working? Is the index the date itself?

Comment: Since the question is about `scorer` we don't really need the rest of the code. You've already dumped "copper.csv", how about posting a trimmed down snapshot of just the relevant columns and a few rows? Then trim your example to reading and processing that dataframe.

Comment: Have just added to the orig post via a link. Seems my DataFrame is indexed by number. IE: 0,1,2,3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you created checks the full columns of the dataframe, instead of the value for a given date. Plus, the `if` and `elif` statements were wrongly indented.

```
def scorer(data, i):
    if(data.loc[i,"sma"] > 0 and data.loc[i,"MlrSlope"] >0 ):
        return 1
    elif (data.loc[i,"sma"] >0 and data.loc[i,"MlrSlope"] <0):
        return 0
    elif(data.loc[i,"sma"] <0 and data.loc[i,"MlrSlope"] >0):
        return 0
    elif (data.loc[i,"sma"] <0 and data.loc[i,"MlrSlope"] <0):
        return -1
```

The function above takes 2 inputs: the dataframe you are working with, and a given value of the index. I suppose the next step is to create a new column with the values of the strategy per date, so the code below should do the job:

```
for i in data.index:
    data.loc[i, 'strategy'] = scorer(data,i)
```

Please let me know if it works, as I was not able to test it in a real dataframe

Comment: Mate you are a legend. This worked perfectly.  Sorry to ask, but I want to make sure that I understand everything going on so as not to have to ask a similar question in the future.

Is my understanding correct: the function scorer now looks at the data in place i.  If the data located in location i of the SMA columns is greater than zero and the data located  in place i column MLRslope will return a 1... then it looks at the rest of the statements. 

Im pretty sure I understood the above. Again thank you very much, and have a great evening ahead.